# How can I change the speed of the lines drawing inside StartCoroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the Start:

```
private void Start()
    {
       StartCoroutine(moveLines());
    }
```

In moveLines:

```
IEnumerator moveLines()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Count; i++)
        {
            allLines[i].SetActive(true);
            counter = 0;
            endPos = allLines[i].GetComponent<EndHolder>().EndVector;

            var dist = Vector3.Distance(endPos, startPos);
            while (counter < 25)
            {
                dist = Vector3.Distance(instancesToMove[0].transform.position, endPos);
                counter++;
                endPos = allLines[i].GetComponent<EndHolder>().EndVector;
                startPos = allLines[i].GetComponent<LineRenderer>().GetPosition(0);

                instancesToMove[0].transform.position =
                    Vector3.MoveTowards(startPos, endPos, counter / 25f * speed);

                allLines[i].GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, instancesToMove[0].transform.position);

                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a global speed variable but it's not changing the speed of the lines drawings.

allLines is a List each GameObject have a LineRenderer component.

instancesToMove is also List this object/s move the same time with the lines.

But I want to make the whole process faster. I want the lines drawing and the inastances to move to be faster. If I change now the speed variable value it will not draw the lines at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `counter` to count to a different value and change the `/ 25f` to that new value as well.  Smaller value = Faster draw.

Your code says "do this 25 times, when it hits 25, the line will be done." Which means you spend exactly 25 frames drawing your line. If you want it to draw slower, you need to change how many frames you spend drawing the line.

This also makes your speed variable...useless. You can remove it entirely.